# What does it mean by "grizzly image"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, idiom-meaning

Recently I watched a video and here is one of the line:

> The grizzly image has since been immortalized as shorthand slang for single-minded cult-like thinking.

When I searched the meaning of "grizzly" on the internet, I saw only the result "grizzly bear". It seems to me that "grizzly" has no meaning standing on its own. Is it so?
Below is the video. The line is at around 0:59.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB-dJaCXAxA

Comment: Try "grisly" instead

Comment: It's **grisly** image.

Comment: "It seems to me that "grizzly" has no meaning standing on its own." This is not true. "Grizzly" also means "grey". In fact, gizzly bears are called grizzly bears because the tips of their hairs are grey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *grisly image*.

[grisly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grisly)

> Causing horror or disgust

Usage Note:

> The words grisly and grizzly are quite different in meaning, though often confused. Grisly means ‘causing horror or disgust’, as in grisly crimes, whereas grizzly is chiefly used with reference to a kind of large American bear, and can also mean ‘grey or grey-haired’

(Oxford dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

The word you intended to search for is **grisly** -- *Causing horror or disgust; gruesome, horrendous, etc.*